# Select all element with same tag name using javascript and highlight content partially

Tags: javascript, html, highlight

I made a code that should highlight searched string but it is not working.
Here is the code:

```
<body>

  <div>div is here</div>
   <div id="divid">

    <div>this is a div 1</div>
    <div> this is a div 2</div>
    <div> this is a div3</div>

  </div>

  <div> another div is here</div>
  </body>
```

Here is a javascript code.

```
  function checkit(){

var hlWord = "div";
        var nregex = new RegExp(hlWord,"gi");
        var div = document.getElementById("divid").getElementsByTagName('div');

        for(var i=0; i <= div.length; i++){

            var div1 = div[i].innerHTML;

            var rword = div1.replace(nregex,"<b>"+hlWord+"</b>");
            div1.innerHTML = rword;

        }


  }
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "*does not work*"? It would be nice of you, to help us to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are begginer mistakes in your code. Let me correct them:

```
  function checkit(){

    var hlWord = "div";                  //Define string that will be emphasized by <b> tag
    var nregex = new RegExp(hlWord,"gi");//Create global, case-insensitive regexp
    var div = document.getElementById("divid").getElementsByTagName('div');  //Get element collection of divs in div#divid

    for(var i=0; i < div.length; i++){  //Loop through my element collection

        var div1 = div[i].innerHTML;    //Get the innerHTML of on of the divs

        var rword = div1.replace(nregex,"<b>"+hlWord+"</b>");  //Surround my string with <b>
        div[i].innerHTML = rword;  //Change the innerHTML back

    }

  }
```

1. You used this `for` condition: `i<=div.length`. This is wrong. Do not forget, that we count from 0 so: `[0, 1, 2, 3].length = 4`. Last element for such array has index 3. The `[]` is an array literal.
2. By mistake, you assigned `div1.innerHTML`. `div1` was a string. The element you want to change is `div[i]`.

### [I made a JSFiddle too!](http://jsfiddle.net/Darker/UPgG8/2/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with you code will be, amongst other problems, that nested `div` elements will be broken. You should use some kind of recursion if you want to highlight the word 'div'.

Here is such a function:

```
function highLight(term,root){
    var allDiv = root.querySelectorAll('div'),
        replacer = function(a){return '<span class="highlight">'+a+'</span>'};
    for (var i=0; i<allDiv.length; i+=1){
        if (allDiv[i].querySelectorAll('div').length){
            highLight(term, allDiv[i]);
        } else {
          var re = RegExp('('+term+')','gi');
          allDiv[i].innerHTML = allDiv[i].innerHTML.replace(re,replacer);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is a [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ka4hz/) to play around with it

A more [**advanced jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/fDznF/)

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors: there you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/55U6j/1/

```
function checkit(){

var hlWord = "div";
        var nregex = new RegExp(hlWord,"gi");
        var divs = document.getElementById("divid").getElementsByTagName('div');

        for(var i=0; i < divs.length; i++){

            var div = divs[i];
            var html =  div.innerHTML;

            var rword = html.replace(nregex,"<b>"+hlWord+"</b>");
            div.innerHTML = rword;

        }


  }
```

Comment: Try this code using: `<div>this is a <div>div 1</div></div>` in the document